# Regex help to parse bind file

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse current added domains from bind zone file...

Sample string

```
net.    86400   in  rrsig   nsec    5   1   86400    
test-name.net.  86400   in  rrsig   nsec
testname.net.   86400   in  rrsig   nsec
```

I have tried following regex...

```
preg_match_all("/(\S+)\.\s+86400\s+in\s+rrsig/", $str, $matches);
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => net. 86400   in  rrsig
            [1] => test-name.net.   86400   in  rrsig
            [2] => testname.net.    86400   in  rrsig
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => net
            [1] => test-name.net
            [2] => testname.net
        )

)
```

It should only returns domains ending with .net tld maybe.

Comment: Are you sure hat the fields are tab separated, which your regex assumes? Based upon the sample string you show, they appear to be space separated. Try `\s+` in place of `\t`.

Comment: I have tried that but its returning duplicate and too many results, and it never picked test-name.net

Comment: Can't you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php ?

Comment: `test-name` has a character (hyphen) not considered a "word" character, so `\w+` will not match it. It only matches a letter or underscore. In place of `\w+` try `[a-zA-Z_-]+`. If the regex picks up too many results, then you need to explain more what you do NOT want to match as well as what you want to match.

Comment: No its not csv file.

Comment: @lurker updated question with sample response.

Comment: The example you gave isn't what I suggested that you try. I suggested replacing your original `\t` with `\s+`, and your `\w+` with `[a-zA-Z_-]+`, or in other words: `/([a-zA-Z_-]+)\.net\.\s+86400\s+in\s+rrsig/`.

Comment: @lurker This doesn't return anything.

Comment: @lurker Yes its returning now but not working for numbers and unicode domains.

Comment: Then try, `preg_match_all("/(\S+)\.net\.\s+86400\s+in\s+rrsig/", $str, $matches);`

Comment: @lurker works! Let me try with few more examples.

Comment: You can take a look at this [https://github.com/neilstuartcraig/TDPBindZoneFileParser](https://github.com/neilstuartcraig/TDPBindZoneFileParser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not made it clear what it is exactly that you want but you can try the following.

```
preg_match_all("/\S+\.(?:net|tld)/", $str, $matches);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test-name.net
            [1] => testname.net
        )

)
```

Or

```
$pattern = "/\S+\.(?:net|tld)\.(?:\t|\s)+86400(?:\t|\s)+in(?:\t|\s)+rrsig/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test-name.net.  86400   in  rrsig
            [1] => testname.net.   86400   in  rrsig
        )

)
```

The `:?` used in both examples makes it so the group is not captured and only matches what is in the`()`. This will reduce results from `preg_match_all` so you don't need to weed through the array to get what you want.

**EDIT**

You can use look ahead `(?=)` to make sure all of the required content is there and then only select the portion you want.

```
$pattern = 
    "/(?=\S+\.(?:net|tld)\.(?:\t|\s)+86400(?:\t|\s)+in(?:\t|\s)+rrsig)\S+\.(?:net|tld)/"
    ;
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
```

In the example the required content is:

```
(?=\S+\.(?:net|tld)\.(?:\t|\s)+86400(?:\t|\s)+in(?:\t|\s)+rrsig)
```

and the desired content is:

```
\S+\.(?:net|tld)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and info. I will try this real quick.

Comment: I have edit the answer and it should now work with unicode domains.

Comment: Second example makes more sense and first example return too many duplicate records because of many dns entries. And second example only returns full string but not domains, how can i grab only domains using second example?

Comment: You can use the regex look ahead operator `?=`. example:  `"/(?=\S+\.(?:net|tld)\.(?:\t|\s)+86400(?:\t|\s)+in(?:\t|\s)+rrsig)\S+\.(?:net|tld)/";` I will add it to the answer.

Comment: You are awesome and thanks for answer with details. This would help me learn advanced regex.